# PHP quiz code (radio buttons wont update global values)

Tags: php

I am making a webpage to ask 15 questions to the user. Based off of the answers to these 15 questions the webpage will determine what kind of element the user would bend (its a reference to Avatar the Last Airbender).

I would like the website to first display a description page ($currentPage = 0). Then when the user clicks the "Next Question" button the $currentPage variable will increase by 1 and the first question will appear with four radio buttons under it as possible answers. Each answer corresponds to an element (air, earth, water, or fire). If a user selects (one radio button only) the score for that element will increase by 1. Then when the user clicks the "Next Question" button the $currentPage variable will increase by 1 again and the next question will appear. At the end of the 15 questions (total of 16 pages including the description page) I will compare all four score to see which value is the greatest to determine which element the user would bend.

I have only coded for 1 question and the description portions, but i can not seem to increase the $earthScore, $waterScore, $fireScore, or $airScore by 1 after selecting the radio button corresponding to the answer and hitting next question.

Could you guys please help me out???

I dont have 10 reputation points so here are the links to screenshots of the webpage:

[Description](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108273736/description.png)

[Question 1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108273736/question%201.png)

The following is my php code from the file benderTest.php:

```
    <!-- Begin Test frame -->
    <form action="benderTest.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">         
    <div class="benderTest">
    <input class="benderNext" type="submit" value="Next Question"/>        
    <?php
    $currentPage = (int)$_GET['currentPage'];
    $waterScore = (int)$_GET['waterScore'];
    $earthScore = (int)$_GET['earthScore'];
    $airScore = (int)$_GET['airScore'];
    $fireScore = (int)$_GET['fireScore'];        

    if($currentPage == 0)  
    {      
        echo "<p class='benderQuestion'>Discover what kind of bender you are! Click next question.</p>";
    }
    else if($currentPage == 1)
    {
        echo "<p class='benderQuestion'>Which battle strategy do you most prefer?</p><br/><br/><br/>"; 
        echo "<input style='margin: 15px;' type='radio' name='earthScore' value='".($earthScore+1)."'><font class='benderAns'>Waiting for the right moment to strike.</font><br><br>";
        echo "<input style='margin: 15px;' type='radio' name='airScore' value='".($airScore+1)."'><font class='benderAns'>Avoid and evade.</font><br><br>";
        echo "<input style='margin: 15px;' type='radio' name='waterScore' value='".($waterScore+1)."'><font class='benderAns'>Turning my opponent's force against him/her.</font><br><br>";
        echo "<input style='margin: 15px;' type='radio' name='fireScore' value='".($fireScore+1)."'><font class='benderAns'>Go completely on the offensive.</font><br><br>";                       
    }  

    $currentPage = $currentPage + 1;  
    ?>       
    <input class="benderHide" name ="currentPage" type="text" value="<?php echo $currentPage; ?>"/>
    </div>  
    </form>            
    <!-- End test frame -->
```

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is working for me. Using [this](http://softwarejunkies.comeze.com/benderTest.php?airScore=1&currentPage=1) url the value in the `airScore` input is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :P copy paste this in random php file, and see how it works.

I'm to sleepy atm to write full explanation, but i will in the morning if you will need one.

```
<!-- Begin Test frame -->
    <form action="" method="post">         
    <div class="benderTest">
    <input class="benderNext" type="submit" value="Next Question"/>        
    <?php

    $currentPage = (int)$_POST['currentPage'];

    $waterScore = (int)$_POST['waterScoreData'];
    $earthScore = (int)$_POST['earthScoreData'];
    $airScore = (int)$_POST['airScoreData'];
    $fireScore = (int)$_POST['fireScoreData']; 



   isset ($_POST['waterScore']) ? $waterScore++ : $waterScore;
   isset ($_POST['earthScore']) ? $earthScore++ : $earthScore;
   isset ($_POST['airScore']) ? $airScore++ : $airScore;
   isset ($_POST['fireScore']) ? $fireScore++ : $fireScore;        


//Question array
    $questions = array (
        "Discover what kind of bender you are! Click next question.",
        "Which battle strategy do you most prefer?",
        "Question number 2! Click next question.",
        "Question number 3! Click next question.",
    );

    $earthAnwser = array (
            1 => "Waiting for the right moment to strike.", 
            2 => "Anwser 2", 
            3 => "anwser 3"
            );
    $airAnwser= array (
        1 => "Avoid and evade.", 
        2 => "Anwser 2", 
        3 => "anwser 3"
        );
    $waterAnwser = array (
        1 => "Turning my opponent's force against him/her.", 
        2 => "Anwser 2", 
        3 => "anwser 3");
    $fireAnwser = array (
        1 => "Go completely on the offensive.", 
        2 =>"Anwser 2", 
        3 => "anwser 3");


        isset($currentPage) ? $currentPage : $currentPage = 0;



        if ($currentPage) { // if current page is bigger than 0 
        echo "<p class='benderQuestion'>" . $questions[$currentPage]. "</p><br/><br/><br/>"; 
        echo "<input style='margin: 15px;' type='radio' name='earthScore' value='1'><font class='benderAns'>". $earthAnwser[$currentPage]."</font><br><br>";
        echo "<input style='margin: 15px;' type='radio' name='airScore' value='1'><font class='benderAns'>". $airAnwser[$currentPage] ."</font><br><br>";
        echo "<input style='margin: 15px;' type='radio' name='waterScore' value='1'><font class='benderAns'>".  $waterAnwser[$currentPage] ."</font><br><br>";
        echo "<input style='margin: 15px;' type='radio' name='fireScore' value='1'><font class='benderAns'>".  $fireAnwser[$currentPage]."</font><br><br>";                       
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="waterScoreData" value="<?php echo $waterScore ;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="earthScoreData" value="<?php echo $earthScore ;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="airScoreData" value="<?php echo $airScore ;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="fireScoreData" value="<?php echo $fireScore ;?>">
        <?php
        } else {

           echo "<p class='benderQuestion'>" .$questions[$currentPage]. "</p><br/><br/><br/>";  
        }

    $currentPage = $currentPage + 1;  
    ?>       

    <input type="hidden" name ="currentPage" type="text" value="<?php echo $currentPage; ?>"/>
    <?php 

        if ($earthScore) echo "<br/>Earth Score: " . $earthScore . "<br/>";
        if ($airScore)  echo "Air Score: " . $airScore . "<br/>";
        if ($waterScore) echo "Water Score: ". $waterScore . "<br/>";
        if ($fireScore) echo "Fire: Score " . $fireScore . "<br/>";
        ?>
    </div>  
    </form>            
    <!-- End test frame -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting your values in the inputs, save your results in `$_SESSION`

```
<?php
// start session at the top of page, before other code
session_start();

// set values on initial page
if(!isset($_GET['currentPage'])) {
    $_SESSION['air'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['earth'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['fire'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['water'] = 0;
}
?>
```

then if the value is checked, increase the value (note, I changed your radio names, see the last code block)

```
$safe_values = array('air','earth','fire','water');

// increase checked value (sanitizing data by checking if field is set, white listed in safe array and if it is a valid Session key)
if(isset($_GET['score']) && in_array($_GET['score'],$safe_values) && isset($_SESSION[$_GET['score']]){
    $_SESSION[$_GET['score']]++;
}
```

Now in your form, use the same radio name -> `name="score"`, and set the value to the element

```
else if($currentPage == 1)
    {
        echo "<p class='benderQuestion'>Which battle strategy do you most prefer?</p><br/><br/><br/>"; 
        echo "<input style='margin: 15px;' type='radio' name='score' value='earth'><font class='benderAns'>Waiting for the right moment to strike.</font><br><br>";
        echo "<input style='margin: 15px;' type='radio' name='score' value='air'><font class='benderAns'>Avoid and evade.</font><br><br>";
        echo "<input style='margin: 15px;' type='radio' name='score' value='water'><font class='benderAns'>Turning my opponent's force against him/her.</font><br><br>";
        echo "<input style='margin: 15px;' type='radio' name='score' value='fire'><font class='benderAns'>Go completely on the offensive.</font><br><br>";                       
    }
```